# Prove that if there is a walk from u to v then there is also a path from u to v.

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph and let u and v be two of its vertices. Prove that if there is a walk from u to v then there is also a path from u to v.

Using induction on length of a path, how can I solve this?

walk: A walk in a graph *G = (V,E)* is a sequence of vertices $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ ... $v_k$ s.t. {$v_i$,$v_i$+1} ∈ E for i = 1, ..., k-1

path: walk with no repeated vertices or # of edges

Comment: You need to properly define what you mean by "walk" and "path". As you may know Graph Theory is naturally notorious for its ambiguous definitions.

Comment: The main difference is that a path doesn't contain a cycle, while a walk could. How can you account for this?

Comment: @Ishfaaq I updated it

Comment: provided u != v

Comment: As an addition: Without induction, I guess one could show that the graph defined by $H := (V(W), E(W))$ (Where V(W) and E(W) denotes the vertices and edges in W, respectively) is connected and thus contains a $u$-$v$ path $P$ in $H \subseteq G$.

Answer (score 14):

We use induction on the length of the walk.

Let $W$ be a walk between $u$ and $v$.

**Base step:** if $|W| = 1$, then $W$ is just the edge $uv$ and it is a $u-v$ path.

**Induction step:** Now assume the statement is true for all $u-v$ walks of smaller size than $W$. If all the vertices in $W$ are distinct, then $W$ is $u-v$ path and we are done.
Otherwise, $W$ has a repeated vertex say $x$. Let $W'$ be the walk obtained by suppressing the section of $W$ between the two repetition of $x$. Obviously $W'$ is $u-v$ walk of smaller length than $W$. By induction hypothesis, $W'$ has $u-v$ path which means that $W$ has $u-v$ path.

Comment: Or just consider a **shortest** walk from $u$ to $v$ and show that it must be a path. Of course that is essentially what you did.

Answer (score 2):

***Hint:***

A walk is an edge sequence. But still can be written down as a sequence of vertices. Suppose there are repeating vertices in this sequence. Say $u$ is such a repeating vertex. Delete all other terms in the sequence till the last occurrence of $u$ in your walk. Do this for all repeating vertices and you will have yourself a path.

I can't see a way to apply induction to this problem. I'm sorry. Although I don't see why you should.

Comment: What you said is pretty much what induction is!

Comment: @hbm: Pardon my idiocy..Don't seem to get it. Would love an explanation..

Comment: If we want to show more clearly why the process you have described works, we will probably appeal to a reasoning like this: "by removing such a sequence of vertices we arrive at a shorter walk. Eventually we would have removed all repeating vertices until we get a path." This reasoning can be made more formal by induction: by removing such a sequence of vertices we arrive at a shorter walk, which by the induction hypothesis contain a path.

Answer (score 2):

Without induction: $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ is a walk from $u$ to $v$ if and only if $(w_1,\ldots,w_k)$ is a walk from $v$ to $u$, where $w_i=v_{k+1-i}$ for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant k$.

Answer (score 1):

@hbm inductive method is also good.

**We can also do it using Constructive method:**

Our algorithm input = walk (sequence of edges and vertices)
Our algorithm output = path (distinct sequence of edges and vertices)

1. pick an element (starting from index 0) and compare with all other elements in string*
2. if any repeating element is found, then remove complete sub-array between repetitive elements and also remove one of repetitive element.
3. repeat step 3 until last element is picked.

*strings are arrays of characters