# Do Every Trail contains a $uv$ path

Tags: graph-theory

Going through proof that Every Walk $W$ contains a $uv$ path [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699765/prove-that-if-there-is-a-walk-from-u-to-v-then-there-is-also-a-path-from-u-to-v) ,i am able to get it down ,but i guessed is it possible that Every trail will always contain $uv$ path ??
Please give a counter example.!!

Comment: These terms are not standard enough for you to give them without explanation. Please give more context; for instance, a source of the proof you're asking about.

Comment: edited !!added the link ! i am okk with walk ,have doubt in trail !!

Comment: If you know that every walk contains a $uv$ path, doesn't that ***include*** the fact that every trail contains  $uv$ path? Isn't every trail a walk?

Comment: You misquoted the post you linked to. It does not say that ***every*** walk contains a $uv$ path, it only says that every walk ***between $u$ and $v$*** contains a $uv$ path.

Comment: @bof sorry mistaken!

Comment: @sourav In what am I mistaken? Please give your definitions of "walk" and "trail".

Comment: Walk may have repeated edges and repeated vertices but trail don't have repeated edges but can have repeated vertices

Comment: That's what I thought. So "walk" is more general than "trail", and the result for walks, which you linked to, includes the result for trails as a special case.

Answer (score 1):

But a trail is also a walk. Since, as was proved in the link you referenced, every walk from u to v contains a path from u to v, it follows that any trail from u to v contains that path as well.